# How to make my program only check inside parenthesis?

Tags: c

The goal of the program is to be able to extract integers in a string(char), only if they are inside a set of parenthesis. I am also suppose to print out an error message if the string doesn't meet these requirements.

For example: `char str = "( 1 2 3)";`
this would print that it found integers 1, 2, and 3. But lets say str was `char str = " 1 2 3( 4 5 6);` would return a call to my error function because it has bad formatting. If the string contains anything else that is not a number or white space it should print error also. Lastly it is suppose to check looking inside the parenthesis until it finds the end parenthesis.

At the moment, I can search thru any string and extract the integers but I cannot figure out how to determine if there are anything else besides numbers and check only inside parenthesis.

```
void scanlist(char *str)
{
    char *p = str;
    while (*p) {
    if ((*p == '-' && isdigit(p[1])) || (isdigit(*p))) {
        int val = strtol(p, &p, 10);
        on_int(val);
    }
    else {
        p++;
    }

}
```

I have tried putting another if statement after the while seeing if it starts with a '(' but it doesn't do anything. Please and thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hold some state regarding your position. For example:

```
int inside_paren = 0;
while (*p) {
    switch (*p) {
    case '(':
        if (inside_paren)
            /* error */
        inside_paren = 1;
        break;
    case ')':
        /* ... */
        inside_paren = 0;
        break;
    default:
        if (!isdigit(*p) || !inside_paren)
            /* error */
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by hold some state?

Comment: This is my first time seeing switch case and I am trying to figure this out. In the case '(' if *p == '(' it changes inside_paren which checks if its inside yet, if not switches it so it is. Then in case ')' if *p == ')' it changes inside_paren to 0 which lets the know that it is outside. Then default is just what it does every time. So would the code to actual extract the would it be under default? Also how would this determine if there is anything besides integers and white space?

Comment: @dLiGHT "default" is what happens when other cases aren't matched. If you look closely, that `if` tests whether there are other characters than what is allowed.

Comment: I dont understand where the code to isolate the integers would be. I was guessing underdefault.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
int main()
    {
        //variable declerations
        int j = 0;
        // str is the string that is to be scanned for numbers
        string  str= "(123)";
        //iterator to point at individual characters in a string 
        //It starts at the beginning of a string
        //a string is an array of characters
        string::iterator p = str.begin();
        //if the iterator that i named p does not find the bracket at the begining 
        //prints out an error massage
        if(*p != '(')
        {
            cout<<"error";
        }
        //else if it finds a bracket at the begining goes into the loop
        // I use *p to veiw the content that the iterator points to 
        // if you only use p you will get the address which is a bunch of wierd numbers like A0Bd5 
        if(*p == '(')
        {
            //while loop to move the iterator p one caracter at a time until reach end of string
            while(p != str.end())
            {
                       // if end bracket is reached end loop
                       if(*p == ')')
                       {
                       break;
                       }
                //if it finds a digit prints out the digit as character not as int! 
                if(isdigit(*p))
                {

                    cout<<*p<<endl;
                }
                //increments the iterator by one until loop reach end of string it breaks
                p++;
            }
        }

        //to pause the screen and view results
        cin.get();

    }
```

Comment: are you using any libraries for this?

Comment: This answer is in C++, but Dlight is asking about C.

Comment: ooh i tthought he was asking c++ for some reason